# COM based .net plugin framework

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 website which has to work with COM plugins. In order to do that I need to define an interface somehow. As far as I understand(I'm not a COM expert) this can be done either in .NET and export it with tlbexp.exe or idl->midl->tlbimp.

I have gone the first way(with tlbexp). I tried IDL too but to no avail(for some reason could cast the implementing COM object back to the tlbimp'ed interface in .NET).

This scenario would be simple if my interface didn't have an event on it:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("EFCFB783-0225-4D45-94CB-9A26B7CC19AF")]
public delegate void ItemStatusChanged(string itemGuid, string itemStatus);

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("35202AE5-392D-4015-993D-29966DA5DE31")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ICOMOutputPlugin
{
    void Method1(string arg);
    void Method2(string arg);
    event ItemStatusChanged ItemStatusChanged;
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("93862C43-503C-4C96-9BAE-944F1087AB77")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ICOMOutputPluginEvents
{
    void ItemStatusChanged(string itemGuid, string itemStatus);
}
```

I export this to tlb with tlbexp.exe and register the .tlb with regtlibv12.
Only this type library will be used by the plugin developers to import the interfaces.

Now I have a C++ project which will be a plugin, I add in VS2010 new simple ATL object and change the IDL to:

```
importlib("stdole2.tlb");
importlib("MyExp.tlb");

[
    uuid(E09BC67A-4192-4CA3-8FD0-5CBFC69B43AC)      
]
coclass DumpToFileOutputPlugin
{
    [default] interface ICOMOutputPlugin;
    [default, source] dispinterface ICOMOutputPluginEvents;
};
```

My first problem here was that for some reason I couldn't add the connection point the 'normal way' via class wizard. It simply doesn't show any source interfaces when I direct it to my MyExp.tlb. So I did that manually(used another .tlb and renamed everything).

So now I have the COM object with these 2 methods:

```
STDMETHOD(add_ItemStatusChanged)(_ItemStatusChanged* value);
STDMETHOD(remove_ItemStatusChanged)(_ItemStatusChanged* value);
```

On the .NET side the plugin manager instantiates the plugins like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID);
comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ICOMOutputPlugin;
comObject.ItemStatusChanged += (guid, status) => ItemStatusChanged(guid, status);
```

the last line miraculously calls the `add_ItemStatusChanged` method on my COM object.

Here I'm stuck, what should I don in this method? my current implementation is:

```
HRESULT CDumpToFileOutputPlugin::add_ItemStatusChanged(_ItemStatusChanged* value)
{
        DWORD cookie;
        HRESULT ret = Advise(value, &cookie);
        _com_error err(ret);
        LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
        return ret;
}
```

ret = CONNECT_E_CANNOTCONNECT(0x80040202) and errMsg says "IDispatch error #2".
Apparently Advise expects the COM object passed to implement the connection point interface `ICOMOutputPluginEvents` which the delegate passed object does not... what can I do?

Am I doing the subscription to the event on the .NET side wrong or the add handler?

Any help how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use "events" in a COM plugin for ASP.Net, just have methods that you call. I.e. a method called `OnEventName` rather than an event.

COM events are just not the right kind of thing for handling web form postbacks.

Comment: my problem has nothing to do with ASP.NET, it's just a COM Interop issue, any other .net app would do to illustrate the problem

Comment: @Bond, you are missing the point. You don't need events. You just don't need them, so avoid the COM interop issue by NOT USING EVENTS. Just have functions with EVENT-LIKE NAMES, and call them when the event happens. This is because COM events are DIFFERENT BEASTS and are a pain to wire up in ASP.NET, as you have just learned.

Comment: The fact that tlbexp exports the event into an add/remove method pair and these methods get invoked when I subscribe to the event on the .NET side makes me think there must be some way to make it work.

Comment: Why are the plugins sourcing events? How can that work in a web application? The plugin is only alive for the duration of a request! Or does it live in global.asax?

Comment: The plugins are not related to requests, they will be created on site startup and will fire events which will be recorded in the DB or to notify connected clients(let's say by using SignalR)

Comment: Then they should not be loaded by ASP.Net but by a separate service which you create specifically to host them. ASP.Net has no capability to handle events in that way - only events originating from http requests.

Comment: ok, but that's still not relevant to the question. Even if I separate them in another service I would have the same issue. I just need a way to implement the add/remove method pair or use totally different approach.

Comment: The question is how to handle events sourced by a COM object in ASP.Net. The answer is DON'T. That's the correct answer. As to handling the events, you should probably rearchitect the system in a way to do away with the events. What triggers them?

Comment: None of this is really relevant to how to handle events, the long and short of which is "not like that". START with a TypeLib written in MS IDL. Since they are plug-ins, you need a more comprehensive understanding of what is going to trigger the events. Network activity? User activity (how)? What else? This will affect your threading model of the thread where the plug-in is going to live. It looks like you haven't really thought about what the plug-ins are going to do.